# How do I configure a virtual host to look in 2 directories and 1 file for the request?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I want to make it so that going to domain.com/xyz will check in web/, if it doesn't exist in web/ then it will check in website/ and if it doesn't exist in either of them it will check in web/app.php

How do I configure the virtual host (with mod_rewrite) to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in your vhost config:

```
RewriteEngine On

# check if it exists in /web
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web%{REQUEST_URI} -d
# if exists, serve the file in /web
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web$1 [L]

# check if it exists in /website
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/website%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/website%{REQUEST_URI} -d
# if exists, serve the file in /website
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website$1 [L]

# otherwise, route through app.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/app.php/$1 [L]
```

The route through app.php just calls `/web/app.php`, it doesn't send anything to the script.

Comment: It should be web/app.php/ followed by anything after the domain. So domain.com/blah/yay would check in web/app.php/blah/yay/

Thanks